# mocked service call is not being used

Tags: python, pytest

I have the model object that looks like this

```
class CatalogModel(BaseModel):
    @property
    def custom_service(self):
        return CustomService()

    async def get_offers(self, catalog_name):
        try:
            svc_response = self.custom_service.get_offers(catalog_name=catalog_name)()
        except BaseException:
            raise SalesForceException()
        return CustomOfferResponse().dump(svc_response)
```

I am trying to write a test for that `get_offers` function (that uses `custom_services` which is connecting to Salesforce)

My test is looking like this. I am using `pytest`, `pytest vcr` etc.

```
class TestCatalogModel:
    catalog_name = 'CATALOG_1'
    
    @freeze_time("2021-07-12")
    async def test_get_offers(self, loop, offers, offers_response):
        with MockUser(ident="test_model_get_offers"):
            with patch(
                "com.services.client.CustomService.get_offers", new=offers
            ):
                eo_offers = await CatalogModel().get_offers(self.catalog_name)
                assert offers_response == eo_offers
```

However when executing the test it fails with the error

```
E   vcr.errors.CannotOverwriteExistingCassetteException: Can't overwrite existing cassette ('/test_api/recordings/2021-07-12/test_get_offers_model/salesforce/auth/client/services_oauth2_token.yaml') in your current record mode ('none').
E   No match for the request (&lt;Request (POST) https://server.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token&gt;) was found.
E   No similar requests, that have not been played, found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...model.py:17: in test_get_offers
    eo_offers = await CatalogModel().get_offers(self.catalog_name)
model.py:24: in get_offers
    raise SalesForceException()
E   ...SalesForceException: Error from Salesforce.
```

As far as I understand it is trying to connect to real Salesforce service, rather than using a mock. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid trying to partially patch methods on classes. Instead I would use inversion of control to allow mock instances to be used during tests. This avoids having to do any patching at all.

```
class CatalogModel(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, custom_service=None):
        if custom_service is None:
            custom_service = CustomService()
        self.custom_service = custom_service

    async def get_offers(self, catalog_name):
        try:
            svc_response = self.custom_service.get_offers(catalog_name=catalog_name)()
        except BaseException:
            raise SalesForceException()
        return CustomOfferResponse().dump(svc_response)
```

Now writing the test becomes much simpler.

```
class TestCatalogModel:
    catalog_name = 'CATALOG_1'
    
    @freeze_time("2021-07-12")
    async def test_get_offers(self, loop, offers, offers_response):
        with MockUser(ident="test_model_get_offers"):
            custom_service = mock.Mock()
            custom_service.get_offers.return_value = offers
            model = CatalogModel(custom_service)
            eo_offers = await model.get_offers(self.catalog_name)
            assert offers_response == eo_offers
```

Comment: What library provides `mock` here? pytest-mock?

Comment: @lapots https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock